# Adding elements to array of structures in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am currently doing a little project, and I want to add an element to a pointer of structures, and a function that does it is in struct. Can i use `this` to do it?

```cpp
    Department* add_dep()
    {
        Department* temp;
        temp = new Department[deps_count];
        for (int i = 0; i < deps_count; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = this[i];
        }
        delete[] this;
        this = new Department[deps_count];
    }
```

This code gives me an error `assignment to this (anachronism)`, and I see why, but I don't see how can I fix this without returning `temp`.
How do I do it then?

Comment: No, you cannot use `this` in this manner. Why are you using a plain `Department[]` array instead of using a `std::vector<Department>` for a dynamic array?

Comment: what exactly you trying to solve?

Comment: `this` is never an array, so `delete [] this` is always wrong. `this` is a pointer to the current instance of the class.

Comment: PS: no return value from `add_dep`

Comment: @jjramsey ah... But what can I use instead of `this`?

Comment: If you have to ask that question, that suggests that you have a lot to learn about C++. I'd recommend starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list